# How to include the milliseconds in Outlook “received” time? (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, timestamp

What is the formula to see milliseconds.

Previous post shows how to add seconds but need more detail.

```
Here is the formula from other post - Format([Received],"ddd yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, with options in Outlook alone, we could not include the milliseconds in Outlook “received” time. I'm afraid that your issue might need VBA methods or other workarounds related to Outlook for developer. I did some research and found some information, just for your reference:

[Matching the way Outlook rounds milliseconds of the SentOn property](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f7413a8f-2c51-4773-af94-ba5a839a78a5/matching-the-way-outlook-rounds-milliseconds-of-the-senton-property?forum=outlookdev)

[Date-time-stamp needs to include "Milli-Seconds"](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22716659/Date-time-stamp-needs-to-include-Milli-Seconds.html)